# Mac OS X Yosemite Python union output error on Eclipse

Tags: python, macos, unions

No sure if appropriate to ask this questions here, since I am a complete noob in Python. I am following the instruction on Gray Hat Python and was working on union coding.

**this is the original code**

```
from ctypes import *

class barley_amount(Union):
    _fields_ = [
                ("barley_long", c_long),
                ("barley_int", c_int),
                ("barley_char", c_char * 8),
                ]

    value = raw_input("Enter the amount of barley to put into the beer vat: 66")
    my_barley = barley_amount(int(value))
    print "Barley amount as a long: %ld" % my_barley.barley_long
    print "Barley amount as an int: %d" % my_barley.barley_long
    print "Barley amount as a char: %s" % my_barley.barley_char
```

according to Mr. Seitz, the output of this script would be

```
Enter the amount of barley to put into the beer vat: 66 

        Barley amount as a long: 66    
        Barley amount as an int: 66
        Barley amount as a char: B
```

and this is what my results from Eclipse looks like

```
Finding files... done.
Importing test modules ... Enter the amount of barley to put into the beer vat: 66
```

can anyone tell me where I did wrong, or what am I missing?
Mr. Seitz's book was written in 2009, and his examples only include window and linux, is there any good intro to python for beginner? for mac users?

Very much appreciate 
Jim

Comment: python is python. none of your code does anything that'd be mac-specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I found

1. The part after `value=...` should probably be un-indented. Currently it thinks that code should be in the class itself, so it's running it as the class is being initialized and giving an error saying barley_amount is not defined. Although that might have just been the case as you were pasting the code into here.
2. I think you might not need the 66 part in the `raw_input`. That's the part *you* are supposed to enter. Like so:

```py
from ctypes import *

class barley_amount(Union):
    _fields_ = [
                ("barley_long", c_long),
                ("barley_int", c_int),
                ("barley_char", c_char * 8),
                ]

value = raw_input("Enter the amount of barley to put into the beer vat:")
my_barley = barley_amount(int(value))
print "Barley amount as a long: %ld" % my_barley.barley_long
print "Barley amount as an int: %d" % my_barley.barley_long
print "Barley amount as a char: %s" % my_barley.barley_char
```

Here is what I get (I typed in the `64` and hit enter):

```
Enter the amount of barley to put into the beer vat: 64
Barley amount as a long: 64
Barley amount as an int: 64
Barley amount as a char: @
```

Not sure if eclipse lets you interact with the command line.

Comment: not sure if I'm doing correctly, i tried to enter 64 in the console and press enter, there is this one comment:                                                  NameError: name 'barley_amount' is not defined
ERROR: Module: chapter1-unions could not be imported (file: /Users/Picarolife/Documents/workspace/Gray hat Python/chapter1-unions.py).
done.unions.py).
done.

Comment: ok thank you so much, i am still not sure exactly where i did wrong, but now it work just fine after i tried copy and paste your code. Thanks again for your time and help!

Comment: @Jim no problem - but were you considering marking this as the correct answer or anything? :)